# Latest progress on Tarski numbers

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, amenability, banach-tarski

Two questions, the first: What is the smallest non negative integer that we do not know yet is the Tarski number of a group?
The second question is the same as in the title: What is the latest progress on Tarski numbers?

Comment: For the second question, I think you may find the following papers interesting: M. Ershov, G. Golan, M. Sapir. The Tarski numbers of groups, Advances in Mathematics, Vol. 284, 2015, 21-53; A. Rejali, A. Yousofzadeh. Configuration of groups and paradoxical decompositions. Bull. Belg. Math. Soc. Simon Stevin 18 (2011), no. 1, 157-172; A. Yousofzadeh, A constructive way to compute the Tarski number of a group, J.
Algebra. Appl, 17, no. 1 (2018), 1850139

Comment: @CarloBeenakker That is, we know that there is a group with Tarski number 5. Could you please provide a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1:** The state of the art as reported in 2014, see [arXiv:1406.2097](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2097), is that the only numbers which are known to be Tarski numbers of some groups are 4,5,6. Tarski numbers $<4$ are forbidden, which suggests that 7 is the answer to the question *"What is the smallest non negative integer that we do not know yet is the Tarski number of a group?"*.

**Q2:** Recent progress, in addition to the references by Manuel Norman: In [arXiv:1603.04212](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04212) it is shown that the Tarski number of Burnside groups is in the range $[6,14]$.

Comment: The last arXiv link is blank.

Comment: broken link fixed, thanks.